# textview color and order not working

Tags: android

I have a problem with the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/search_list_leaf"
tools:context=".Flowers_List">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="112dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SEARCH YOUR FLOWER"
    android:textColor="#030303"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/C"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="179dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/D"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="D"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="241dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/E"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="E"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="310dp" />
```

The problem is that, even if I change color with the command android:textColor="@color/colorIwant" I get a default color which is green (don't know why) when I run the application, while I have the right color in the design. Another problem is that even if I place all the letters in order on the design and then I apply contraint, when I launch the application I get all the letters distributed in a messy way.

What do you think the problem is about?

Comment: about the messy order issue at run-time, it's because you haven't constrained your layout childs properly. you've given absolute constraints which might differ in look, in your device than in android studio preview. try to provide constraints to your child views.

Comment: Have you defined an app-wide color for `TextViews` in your styles? Also, `ConstraintLayout` can be a pain if you don't apply the constraints and relations well.

Comment: how should I do to apply constraints well? Can you give me an example with two letters?

Comment: Please go through this blog on [how to use constraintlayout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I place all the letters in order on the design and then I apply contraint, when I launch the application I get all the letters distributed in a messy way.

That's because you have not put necessary constraint to child TextViews, but the absolute positions.

I tried to solve this issue, see below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/A" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="SEARCH YOUR FLOWER"
    android:textColor="#030303"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/C"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/B" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/D"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="D"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/E"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="E"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/D"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

As you can see, each child TextView is now constrained both sides--vertically and horizontally to the `parent`, that is the rootview-constraintlayout or other child view.
For example, the constraint `constraintEnd_toEndOf` will align the **end** of this view to **end** of another view. Same way, other constraints work and are applied.
 
You can also give horizontal and vertical bias to position them properly. Hope this helped a little to understand how constraint works.

Answer (score 0):

> for order https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855782/7616371 this is correct
>   and for change textColor you can use :-

```
android:textColor="#fff"
```

> and for textview background color

```
android:background="#fff"
```

Comment: android:textColor doesn't work, I don't know why, maybe because I have put on the letters clickableSpan